# Incomplete Execution of Callbacks on jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have 2 js methods which do an AJAX post to the server and display results accordingly.

1) Delete - Delete upon callback 'hides' the deleted element and does not the refresh the page

```
function DeleteRule(ruleId) {

    var deleteRuleAction = $('#delete-rule-action').val();

    $.post(deleteRuleAction, { ruleId: ruleId }, function(data) {
      if (data.Status == 'Success') {
        alert(data.Messages[0]);
        $('#rule-details-' + ruleId).fadeOut(500);
        $('#div-rule-button-' + ruleId).fadeOut(500);
        activeRuleId = null;
      }
      else
          alert(data.Messages[0]);
    }, 'json');
}
```

2) Save - Save upon callback needs to refresh the page to show the newly added element along with existing elements

```
function SaveRule() { 

    var ruleId = $('#rule-id').val();   
    var saveOrUpdateRuleAction  = $('#add-or-edit-rule-action').val();

    $.post(saveOrUpdateRuleAction, { ruleId: ruleId }, function(data) {
        if (data.Status == 'Success') {
            alert(data.Messages[0]);
            location.reload(true);  
// This is supposed to reload the page after saving the element. 
// But the page gets reloaded without display the alert on the previous line.
        }
        else
            alert(data.Messages[0]);
    }, 'json');
}
```

I call this Save function as :

`<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:Save()">`

Problem: The callback function in Save does not get called at all and the page gets refreshed automatically. During the AJAX call, the object that was to be saved gets saved to the database. But, the code inside the callback function does not get executed.

I was suggested the following hack to make it work

`<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:Save(); return false;">`

I was told that 'return false;' stops the page from automatically reloading. However, this does not make sense since my Delete, which should not get reloaded, does not have this hack to stop it from reloading.

Upon using FireBug, Delete showed a successful POST and a return of JSON data. However Save (without the hack) showed an 'abort'

Comment: apologies for the typo: Save() is SaveRule()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you check with normal button...by change its type="button" ?

Comment: Solved by changing the type to "button".
Thank you :)